# Is there an alternative authentication for woocommerce api?

Tags: wordpress, rest, delphi, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm facing a big challenge to make my Delphi application look at Api's from Woocommerce. 
I got the GET, I got the POST, but now I'm stuck to the PUT in the Rest.
I thought that with the same function that POST would do I could do the PUT, but I get the message that I am not allowed to change. What does not make sense, I can create but not change?

Lowered I'll list the way I'm doing POST, and a second code where I made some changes trying to make the PUT.

Remembering that I already tried to do with the POST code just by changing the method to rmPUT, and the PUT code, I get the message that the signature is invalid.

If anyone knows how to help me please, if not, my last alternative is to go behind a way to change the type of authentication of the Woocommerce API, which I do not know if it's possible ...

```
//My Procedure for POST  
procedure TForm1.Criar;
var
  s,r: String;
begin
  RESTRequest.ResetToDefaults;
  RESTClient.ResetToDefaults;
  RESTResponse.ResetToDefaults;
  RESTResponseDSAdapter.ResetToDefaults;
  WooAuth.ResetToDefaults;

  WooAuth.ConsumerKey := edtConsumerKey.Text;
  WooAuth.ConsumerSecret := edtConsumerSecret.Text;

  RESTClient.BaseURL := edtBaseURL.Text;
  RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  RESTRequest.Resource := '/products/categories';

  RESTRequest.AddParameter('name', edtNomeGrupo.Text);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('description', edtDescGrupo.Text);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_consumer_key', edtConsumerKey.Text);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_signature_method', WooAuth.SignatureMethod);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_nonce', WooAuth.nonce);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_timestamp', WooAuth.timeStamp.DeQuotedString);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_version', WooAuth.Version);
  s := WooAuth.SigningClass.BuildSignature(RESTRequest, WooAuth);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_signature', s);
end;

//My Procedure for PUT
procedure TForm1.Atualizar;
var
  s,r: String;
begin
  RESTRequest.ResetToDefaults;
  RESTClient.ResetToDefaults;
  RESTResponse.ResetToDefaults;
  RESTResponseDSAdapter.ResetToDefaults;
  WooAuth.ResetToDefaults;

  WooAuth.ConsumerKey := edtConsumerKey.Text;
  WooAuth.ConsumerSecret := edtConsumerSecret.Text;

  RESTClient.BaseURL := edtBaseURL.Text;
  RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPUT;
  RESTRequest.Resource := '/products/categories';
  RESTRequest.ResourceSuffix := '16?name={name}&description={description}&oauth_consumer_key={oauth_consumer_key}&oauth_signature_method={oauth_signature_method}&oauth_nonce={oauth_nonce}&oauth_timestamp={oauth_timestamp}&oauth_version={oauth_version}&oauth_signature={oauth_signature}';

  RESTRequest.AcceptEncoding := 'identity';
  RESTClient.AcceptEncoding := 'identity';

  RESTRequest.AddParameter('name', edtNomeGrupo.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('description', edtDescGrupo.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_consumer_key', edtConsumerKey.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_signature_method', WooAuth.SignatureMethod, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_nonce', WooAuth.nonce, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_timestamp', WooAuth.timeStamp.DeQuotedString, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_version', WooAuth.Version, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
  s := WooAuth.SigningClass.BuildSignature(RESTRequest, WooAuth);
  RESTRequest.AddParameter('oauth_signature', s, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkURLSEGMENT);
end;
```

Comment: Do you have a working client code in a different language? In this case you may compare the network traffic.

Comment: To be honest, I did not get to test in another language, however, I was thinking of using the code that Postman generates for PHP and to do the test, although I do not see difference in the past parameters since they are the same ones that I went through Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "REST Debugger" by Delphi with basic authentication?

The link(https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Getting-started-with-the-REST-API) contains a "getting started". Maybe, it would help you. Maybe, there are a connection issues, like bellow.

> Server does not support POST/DELETE/PUT
>   Ideally, your server should be configured to accept these types of API request, but if not you can use the _method property.

For sure, you are using other method to connect. Maybe, you could use "basic authentication" instead of.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)